# Finding points of intersection when two spheres intersect

Tags: math, collision

I have the center (xyz - in 3 dimensional space) and the radius of two spheres A and B.

Now I have to figure out a point or more than 1 point where these spheres meet. It is fairly easy to figure out if the two spheres collide or not, but how do I find out the points of intersection of 2 spheres?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean the circle of intersection, right?

Comment: The circle that 2 spheres makes when they collide or intersect - Yes !

Comment: what happens when we have N spheres?

Answer (score 2):

If the radius of the smaller sphere is A, and the bigger is B, and their centers are D units apart, then the points of intersection are on a circle of radius r centered on a point directly between  the centers of the two spheres, which is y units from the center of the bigger sphere, and x units from the center of the other, where

y  = 1/2 (D + (B^2 - A^2)/D)

and

x  = 1/2 (D - (B^2 - A^2)/D)

with radius

r  =  B^2 - x^2  =  A^2 - y^2

If you need the equation for this circle the best way is to represent it as a set of three parameterized equations, where the x, y, and z coordinates are each expressed a a function of some t, which represents the  radius vector trraveling around the circle once, from zero to 2PI...

To construct these equations, think about expressing the point which is the radius r from the center, on the 2D plane which is normal to the line between the two spheres.

Check out this [link](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/math99/math99075.htm) for some iedas on how to do this..

Derivation is as follows: draw a line between the centers of the two spheres. Label it as D
Designate a point on this line as the center of the final solution circle label it as point O
Label the smaller portion of D as x, and the large portion as y
draw a line from O perpindicular to D, for some distance r to represent the radius of the solution circle
Label the end of this radius as Q
Now draw B between the center of the larger sphere to Q and A from the center of smaller sphere and Q

From Pythagoras:
 B^2 = y^2 + r^2   and A^2 = x^2 + r^2
so, after eliminating r and a bit of algebra,
   y-x  =  (B^2 - A*2) / (x+y)
But x+y = D so,

y-x = (B^2 - A*2) / D

Adding the equation x+y=D to the above eliminates the x, giving

2y = D  + (B^2 - A*2) / D
or,

```
y = 1/2 (  D  + (B^2 - A*2) / D  )
```

Comment: This can't be right because the units don't work (i.e., it doesn't make sense to add D to B^2).  Maybe it should be sqrt(B^2-A^2)?

Comment: @tom,  Yes, you're right I missed a D when I transcribed the formulas.  I will add the derivation

Answer (score 2):

The curve where they intersect is a circle.  The equation for the radius of the circle is a bit complicated, but is shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html), in eqn. 8, and this distance of the circle from the center of one of the spheres is shown in eqn. 5.

Comment: that is a false, the curve of intersection is not a circle.

Comment: @Dominar: I'm not quite sure whether or not you're serious here, but if you read the link in my post, you'll see that the curve of intersection is a circle.