# Determine the points of intersection between N spheres

Tags: performance, geometry, scientific-computing, computation

Just wanted to know what is the best approach (in terms of speed and accuracy) to determine the points of intersection on N spheres (it was asked for two spheres [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048701/finding-points-of-intersection-when-two-spheres-intersect)); wanted to know what would be the best language to do this. More detailed explanation about what I want to do is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/vertices-of-intersection-between-n-spheres).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As near as I can tell, you are asking for the intersection loci of each pair of N 3D spheres.
Counting symmetry, there are N * (N-1) / 2 pairs.

So take each pair.
If the distance between centers is greater than the sum of their radii, there is no intersection.
(Edit: Or, as @Ben points out, if the distance is less than the difference of radii, there is also no intersection.)

If it is equal, the intersection is a single point, easily found on the line segment between centers.
If it is less, the locus is a circle, not a point.

To find the center of that circle and its radius, you're going to need to take a plane slice through the two spheres.
That reduces the problem to finding the intersection of two circles.
For that you need the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

**Elaborated:** Look at that Wikipedia diagram. *a* and *b* are the radii of the two spheres, and *c* is the distance between centers.
Use the second-to-last equation and solve for *cos(alpha)*.
From that you can easily get *sin(alpha)*.
Then *b sin(alpha)* is the radius of the circle,
and *b cos(alpha)* is the distance to its center.
(Note - this doesn't call any trig functions, only *sqrt*.)

Once you know the center and radius of the circle of intersection, the circle itself is just in a plane normal to the line segment connecting the sphere centers.

Beyond that, I'm not really sure what you want.

Comment: Missed a case: one sphere is entirely contained within the other, the intersection is empty.

Comment: @Ben: Another case: If the distance is 0 and the radii are equal, the intersection is a sphere :-)

Comment: the solution you propose is perfect for 2 spheres, but I am talking about thousands of spheres. I want to determine the resulting outer surface area

Comment: @gpu_drug: I still don't understand what you need. Outer surface area of what? Could you explain it in 2D with a bunch of circles?

Comment: in 2D, for a set of overlapping circles, I need the perimeter of the resulting figure; the same idea in 3D for spheres and outer area

Comment: @gpu_drug: That's called the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right, you want all intersections of at least two spheres from a group of N spheres, right?

If so, this is acually not an easy problem for high performance computing, at least not if you need an accurate solution.
This problem is also solved when calculating the "Reduced Surface" of molecules:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8906967

There are several publications on how to efficiently calculate these points and circles, but it is not an easy task.
I believe there was a publication to calculating these values with CUDA, but I don't remember the details. Google (Scholar) should be able to help you in this direction.

However, depending on what you want to achieve, there can be easier solutions.
So, perhaps you could detail your question?

Comment: I want to do this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/vertices-of-intersection-between-n-spheres